# if (cin >> number_1) doesn't work

Tags: c++, if-statement, visual-studio-2013

Im Reading a c++ book called Programming Principles and Practice Using C++.

And im in a chapter where you do drills with if statments.

One drill is to make it so when you type 1-4 it says it in letters.  1 = one , 3 = three and so on. But i can't make a correct if statment it seems.

Here is my code :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open() {
    char ch; cin >> ch;
}


int main()
{
    cout << "Enter 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4\n";
    int number_0 = 0;
    int number_1 = 1;
    int number_2 = 2;
    int number_3 = 3;
    int number_4 = 4;



    if (cin >> number_0){
        cout << "Zero";
    }

    if (cin >> number_1){
        cout << "One";
    }

    if (cin >> number_2){
        cout << "Two";
    }

    if (cin >> number_3){
        cout << "Three";
    }

    if (cin >> number_4){
        cout << "Four";
    }

    keep_window_open();

}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @MaxJonson   You have obviously been told to avoid "magic numbers" in your code! But is number_1 really any more meaningful than just plain 1? Named constants (they should also be declared `const` )are useful **when they provide more information than the number on its own**

Comment: Indeed doesn't work is not precise enough but here you don't need more precision to see that the use of cin is completely wrong. cin is used to get the input from a user. From there you can afterwards compare that input with different values with == and using different if and else if ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding of `cin` is skewed.

`cin` will read a value input from `stdin` (in your case the keyboard) into a variable.

```
cin >> number_0;
```

Reads a value into `number_0`. You could do

```
int x;
cin >> x;
if(x == 0) {
    cout << "That's a zero!" << endl;
}
```

or even:

```
const int number_0 = 0; //Store 0 just in case math changes
if(x == number_0) {
    cout << "That's a zero!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: what does the x mean in your second explanation? thanks

Comment: @MaxJonson `x` is just some integer variable. I declare it in my first example as `int x;`